# jquery to get next input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of checkboxes. Each of them is associated with one input field. When the checkbox is checked, I would like to set the input field is editable, i.e. **disabled** attribute as **false**. Otherwise, the input field is readonly. Code for one pair of such checkbox and input field is like below (all these code is included in one **section** called **competencies** :

```
<label class="checkbox span3">
<input id="IT_OS_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="IT_OS" name="competency_checkbox[]">
IT - OS
</label>
<div class="controls">
<input id="IT_OS_input" class="input-xxlarge" type="text" name="competency_input[]" disabled="true" placeholder="mots clés séparés par virgule">
</div>
```

So I am trying to use Jquery's **on** method to fire the event for each checkbox. Code is as below :

```
$("#competencies").on('change', '.checkbox', function (event) {
    var orig_val = event.target.parent().next('div').find('input').attr('disabled');
    alert(orig_val);
});
```

For simplicity, I just want to check the selector works fine, however, this code doesn't work. and in firebug, error message is **TypeError: event.target.parent is not a function**. 
Can anyone help me figure this out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#competencies").on('change', '.checkbox', function (event) {
    var orig_val = $(event.target).parent().next('div').find('input').attr('disabled');
    alert(orig_val);
});
```

Just need to wrap the `event.target` to get the jQuery object.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but the **attr** function doesn't return the correct value, i.e. either **false** or **true**. It returns always **disabled**, any ideas ?

Comment: try to use `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: I am curious why `prop` works while `attr` doesn't. Due to different JQuery version or it varies from different navigators ?

Comment: See, the difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

Comment: You can find more details on this in [prop API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)